# Unable to open windows Camera using ImagePicker

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-windows, flutter-image-picker

i am using image_picker: ^1.0.4 package for picking image from camera and gallery. it is working fine for android and ios but in windows camera is not opening. documentation suggests that to use custom camera delegate. i tried to put things together but nothing worked.

```
final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );
```

I tried following piece of codes

```
import 'package:image_picker_platform_interface/image_picker_platform_interface.dart';
// ···
class MyCameraDelegate extends ImagePickerCameraDelegate {
  @override
  Future<XFile?> takePhoto(
      {ImagePickerCameraDelegateOptions options =
          const ImagePickerCameraDelegateOptions()}) async {
    return _takeAPhoto(options.preferredCameraDevice);
  }

  @override
  Future<XFile?> takeVideo(
      {ImagePickerCameraDelegateOptions options =
          const ImagePickerCameraDelegateOptions()}) async {
    return _takeAVideo(options.preferredCameraDevice);
  }
}

// ···
void setUpCameraDelegate() {
  final ImagePickerPlatform instance = ImagePickerPlatform.instance;
  if (instance is CameraDelegatingImagePickerPlatform) {
    instance.cameraDelegate = MyCameraDelegate();
  }
}
```

but still getting following issue

> ImageSource.camera is not supported unless a cameraDelegate is set

if someone has working code then please guide what's wrong or share your implementation.

Comment: You haven't mentioned it, but have you set the permissions for info.plist and androidmanifest.xml? have you looked at [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera)?

Comment: Yes i have set permissions and as i mentioned both platfroms working fine. My question is about Windows Camera.